# Display the progress of completion while the program is being executed

Tags: c, loops

I want to display the progress of my C program in percentages while it is running. The actual work in the program whose progress should be measured is confined in a loop. Here is what I tried:

```
int i;
int to = 100000000;

while (i++ < to) {
    printf("\rPercent done: %d", (100 * i)/to);
}
```

Comment: It would be slow as hell but it should work, when you initialize i.

Comment: @KamiKaze, How do you make a live one? Where it updates itself?

Comment: Apart from your code being broken, you can't do what you ask for with pure standard C. You will have to use the console API for the given OS to set the console cursor where you like it, and then implement multi-threading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Might be a dumb question, but how does one display a progress while
>   the program is running?

Not like this.

You have multiple issues:

- Your `i` is uninitialized, so the program will print garbage. (Fix: -> `int i = 0;` instead)
- Your "progress counter" will only count the progress while in the loop. As soon as `Percent done: 100` will be printed, only the loop will be over.
- You're printing 100 million lines to the console. Maybe think that through again.
- With `(i*100)/to` you're hitting integer overflow about half way through, so use `i / (to / 100)` instead. Notice depending on the compiler the compiler could optimize that out by itself.

A little less obnoxious way would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int i = 0;
    int to = 100000000;

    while (i++ < to) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            printf("\rPercent done: %d",  i / (to / 100));
        }
        dostuff();
    }
    printf("\rLoop finished");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this will only accurately reflect how far the program has come executing the loop. Any work before/after the loop will not be measured by this.

This only prints a console message for every full percent. Still obnoxious that you're getting 100 console messages, but nowhere near as bad as 100.000.000 (!) calls to `printf`. Still though, that's still a performance impact.